# Enable https on docker container in aws ec2

Tags: docker, .net-core, amazon-ec2

I have created Dotnet core web API and converted it as a docker image and I am running docker container in AWS EC2 Instance,

now I am able to access web API through my EC2 public address with my specific port.
eg: http://12.12.34.12:2900 - this is a sample IP address

now i want to run my ec2 public address in https, how to enable an SSL certificate and how to map with my docker container.